# To be a subspace the sum of two vectors in a solution set must be in it too?

Tags: linear-algebra

Good morning,

I just have a quick question to make sure I'm interpreting the properties correctly of a subspace. I know for a subspace to exist, then it must:

1. Contain the zero set in its solutions.
2. Satisfy the closure axiom of addition: if $\vec{v},\vec{w} ∈ V$, then $(\vec{v}+\vec{w}) ∈ V$.
3. Satisfy the closure axiom of scalar multiplication: if $\vec{v} ∈ V$, then $c \cdot \vec{v} ∈ V$.

To clarify my understanding with an example to see if I'm looking at it completely wrong: if $S = \{a,b,c ∈ \mathbb{R}^3\}$ is some solution set satisfying some equation $a^2 = b - c$:

In this case it would not be a subspace, because the vector sum of two solutions would violate the addition closure axiom:

\begin{align*}
\vec{u} =
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 
\end{bmatrix}
\;\;\;
(1)^2=(1)-(0)=1
\;\;\;\\
\vec{v}=
\begin{bmatrix}
2 \\ 6 \\ 2
\end{bmatrix}
\;\;\;
(2)^2=(6)-(2)=4
\;\;\;
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
\vec{u} + \vec{v} =
\begin{bmatrix}
3 \\ 7 \\ 2
\end{bmatrix}
\;\;\;
(3)^2 \neq (7) - (2)
\end{align*}

Because the vector sum of the two valid solutions is not also on the solution plane, does this mean that this is not a subspace then?

Comment: Yes, you have proved that the set is not a subspace.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is exactly what it means. That subset of $\Bbb R^3$ is not a (vector) subspace, for the reason you have found (there are other reasons too, but you there is no need to demonstrate more than one).